# JPA Updating Entity by sub-entity and CRUDRepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

The title of the post might not make sense but here is the issue, I have Administrator and User entities as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "administrators")
public class Administrator extends User {...


@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {...
```

This is how its being executed:

```
Administrator administrator = new Administrator();
User user = //get the existing user by username
administrator.setUserId(user.getUserId());
administrator.set...
// then save using registration service
registrationService.save(administrator);
```

here is the registration service

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {
    @Autowired
    AdministratorRepository administratorRepository ;

    public void addAdministrator(Administrator administrator){
        administratorRepository.save(administrator);
    }
}
```

here is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface AdministratorRepository extends UserBaseRepository<User> {

}
```

and here is UserBaseRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserBaseRepository<T extends User> extends CrudRepository<T, Integer> {

}
```

When a user needs to be made admin, I create a new Administrator Entity instance and set its userId with existing userId that I have in users table (i.e. for User entity).

Now data is stored in Administrator table BUT a new row is created in users table and it doesn't not update the user with the userId that I set in Administrator instance. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the whole code of the two entities. and also how you set the id

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Please have a look now

Comment: you use `AdministratorRepository extends UserBaseRepository<User>` shouldn't that be `AdministratorRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Administrator>`